# Is it possible to use pseudo-elements with the :is() pseudo-class?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

Can something like this be written using the `:is()` pseudo-class?

```
div p,
div p::before,
div p::after {
    /* selectors */
}
```

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
div :is(p, p::before, p::after) {
    /* selectors */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot.

> Pseudo-elements cannot be represented by the matches-any pseudo-class; they **are not valid** within `:is()`. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#matches)</sup>